# Can a function be analytic only inside a given curve??

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, analytic-functions

A function can be analytic only inside a circle. For example the function $g(z)= 1+z+z^2+...$ is only analytic inside the unit circle and nowhere else. This example can be modified to fit into any other circle.

Similarly,

Is it possible that a function is only analytic inside a rectangular strip?

What about any general curves?

Comment: Use conformal maps to map unit circle to rectangular strip. For general curve ... I don't know.

Comment: by RMT for any Jordan curve $J$ its interior can be mapped bi-conformally to the interior of the circle with the map extending to a homeomorphism on the boundary, so if you pick a function with the natural boundary the unit circle ( and for example st $|f(\alpha r)| \to \infty, r \to 1$ for a dense set $|\alpha|=1$ like in the $1+z+z^2+z^4++z^8+...$ case) that behavior continues at $J$ when transformed by the Riemann mapping; this can be easily generalized to other domains too